# CSS styling - right side of the page spilling over far to the right on wide screens

Tags: html, css, firebug

I have an HTML page. On my 15 inch laptop screen, it looks ok. But people with a wider screen have reported that the text on the right side of the screen is spilling far to the right.

If I place the view-source HTML, it will be very long. So I am posting the link to the page. Please do not consider this as me advertising the site (If people complain, I will replace the link with the html).

I am suspecting I need to wrap something in some div, but not certain. I am looking at it with firebug, and it seems that the issue is happening right after the Google ad, but I am not certain.

Advice for how to fix the right-spill are much appreciated.
The site is problemio.com

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: In Firefox you can use that "X-Ray"-like feature right? It should be fairly easy to see where some padding or margin is pushing your content aside. Otherwise try to test some negative margin to see if some overflow is causing it.

Comment: @Allendar yes, the problem is that on my screen, there is no page elements which are being pushed to the right since my screen is a regular size, so I can't reproduce the issue really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a width or max-width on your a container div.

For your site, you have a div with no ID or class associated with it (the one just above your banner). Try setting a `width: 1200px` or `max-width: 1200px` on that div (or whatever size you want)

If you want your site to be centered, also add a `margin: 0 auto;` on the element you set the width limit too.

This is the current structure of your site:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">  <-- make this your wrapper
    <div class="banner" .....></div>
    <div id="body_container"> .....
```

For your CSS:

```
.wrapper { 
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: is it best to have the margi: 0 auto code in the body css definition?

Comment: It won't hurt but I would suggest leaving the body element alone and using a wrapper div instead.

Comment: Yeah, agreed with @Michael. I wouldn't touch the body tag and use a wrapper div.

Comment: @Michael, just because I'm curious: Why is that?

Comment: @LinusCaldwell There isn't really a technical reason not to, it's more a personal preference for me.  It gives more control over elements especially for any edits in the future.  There is not really a reason not to add the wrapper, and can be beneficial if anything is added in the future that needs one, you have one ready to go.  I always code a wrapper into all of my websites, some websites I even have an outer wrapper and an inner wrapper.

Comment: Well sometimes you want to have elements in your site that span across the entire width (an image slider, for example), but you wouldn't want your text to span the entire page. If you limit the width of your site by setting the width on the body, you wouldn't be able to easily have those full-width elements and also easily incorporate smaller width elements.

Comment: @Michael, so, it's for flexibility. I thought so, just wanted to know if there is another reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Give your `<body/>` a `width` or `max-width`:

```
body {
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your site a wrapper like this:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

......... REST OF SITE HERE ..........

</div>
</body>
```

On wrapper define the following:

```
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1140px; /* you cna change this to whatever px width you want */
margin: 0 auto; /* center */
}
```

This will center your site, give it a max width in PX and have it stretch the full amount that it can until it hits that limit.